# Deploy a shiny app - reactiveValues not found

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am trying to `deploy` my shiny app on `shinyapps.io`. The app runs fine in my console but when I deploy my app I get errors for `reactiveValues`, such as:

```
object 'Logged' not found
```

OR

```
Error in reactiveValues(Logged = Logged, registed = registed, Foget = Foget,  :  object 'Logged' not found
```

My script is more than 1000 lines, so, I was not sure that it is a good way to upload the whole script, that's why I decided to put the first few lines from the server that are about the `reactiveValues`.

Appriciate!

```
server = (function(input, output,session) {
Logged = FALSE;
registed = FALSE;
Foget = FALSE;
Started = FALSE;
tested = FALSE;
Saved = FALSE; 
USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged,registed = registed, Foget=Foget, Started=Started,tested=tested,Saved=Saved)
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should end by the following line:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as global variable using "<<-" I would suggest you to declare all variable as global variable.